# Error during cast of an object to std::string with proper operator-overloading

Tags: xcode, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

Follwing short programm will run perfect with VS 2013 and reach the marked point. But in XCode the compiler will show an error due ambiguous constructor. How to work around?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class atest
{
public:
    explicit operator const char *()
    {
        return "";
    }
    template<class T> operator T()
    {

    }
    operator std::string()
    {
        return std::string("Huhuhu");
    }
    template<class T> atest &operator =(T value)
    {

    }
    atest &operator =(const std::string &value)
    {
        return *this; // I want to reach this point
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    atest tst;

    //   auto a = (std::string)tst;
    std::string astr;

    // do some stuff

    astr=tst; // I wanna keep this line

    return 0;
}
```

Clang is not able to distinguish between different constructor where VS2013 is taking the right one. I search now for a way to exclude the "const char *" template of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) have multiple [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking single arguments, and since you provide both a conversion operator for `std::string` *and* a generic any-type conversion operator, the compiler simply don't know which constructor to pick.

Comment: @MartinSchlott Your edit will not change things, it's that you have a generic any-type conversion operator that causes the trouble here. Having such an operator is usually a sign of bad design, unless you really need it you should remove it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The error is at line `astr=tst;`. I think `atest &operator =(const std::string &value)` is the culprit here. Would constructor come into picture here?

Comment: @rockoder No, that assignment operator is invoked when assigning a `std::string` *to* an `atest` instance (e.g. `tst = astr`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written far too many overloaded functions. The only function you need is this:

```
operator std::string()
{
    return std::string("Huhuhu");
}
```

Comment rest all and your code would work just fine.