# Error with cast operator and std::string in a class

Tags: xcode, c++11, operator-overloading

I broke down a problem I already tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27020185/1922748) in following problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class atest
{
public:
    operator std::string()
    {
        return std::string("Huhuhu");
    }
    operator int()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    atest tst;
    std::string astr;

    astr=tst;
    int i=0;
    i=tst;
    return 0;
}
```

std::string seems to have several constructors which even cover int. I got a class which need to be cast able to std::string but also to an integral type. As the assign (=) operator is not overide able outside a class definition I got no Idea how to get the above program running. 
It is bad design but it is worth noting that VS2013 has no problem with above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*explicit conversion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

```
explicit operator std::string()
~~~~~~~
{
    return std::string("Huhuhu");
}
```